# how do I make this sort of uniformly torn paper border with CSS?

Tags: css

as you can see in the image, it isn't just a dashed border.. but it's like.. a double dashed border where each dash is offset by the other.

[image]

How do I make this with CSS?

Comment: use a border, add an outline, you'll get pretty close, otherwise use background images.

Comment: Could you link the website where you saw this? That way we can take a look at the code that created it.

Comment: I saw it in an image. But I figure CSS3 is versatile enough, someone must know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simulate this with nested divs.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="border1">
    <div class="border2">
        <!-- Your content here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.border1 {
    border: 1px gray dotted;
}
.border2 {
    border: 1px gray dotted;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Also, [here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hXqpz/) to see this in action.

Comment: if I only want the border on one side, the dashing / dotting syncs, and creates stripes =\ http://jsfiddle.net/fEwEp/2/

Comment: @TheLindyHop:  In that case, you can add margin-left/right:.5px --> http://jsfiddle.net/hXqpz/2/

Comment: @TheLindyHop: Just want to warn you that it won't look nicely with the dash for some zoom levels (that's why I went for dotted).  Note:  To test zooming in most browsers, hold CTRL and scroll your mouse-wheel.

Comment: how come you used 0.5px? chrome doesn't render < 1px =\

Comment: @TheLindyHop:  It made it slightly closer to your picture in Firefox, so I went with it.  I didn't realize that broke it in Chrome, so that's good to know, and you can just use the 1px version of it :)  http://jsfiddle.net/hXqpz/4/

Answer (score 1):

If you want a border around the whole element, use border+outline, **Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fEwEp/**

```
<div>Border around box</div>

div {
    border: 1px #333 dashed;
    outline: 1px #333 solid;
}
```

If you only want a border at one side (eg top), nest two divs, and add borders to them.
**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fEwEp/1/**

```
<div class="border-top">
    <div>Border at top</div>
</div>

.border-top {
    border-top: 1px #333 solid;
}
.border-top > div {
    border-top: 1px #333 dashed;
}
```

Comment: for the border on just one side (top), how do you get them both to be dashed, and still alternating?

Comment: @TheLindyHop Add a padding to the first div element. **See http://jsfiddle.net/fEwEp/3/**

Answer (score -1):

I'm not quite sure how it works off hand, but you could use border-image.

Comment: If you don't know how it works, how can you possibly recommend it?